# Passing the type of a class as a parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to create a function that takes a type as a parameter?

I am looking for something along the java equivalent of

```
public <T> T getObject(String data, Class<T> type){
    return ObjectMapper.parseTo(data, type);
}
```

I have tried typeof but I cannot seem to find any way to specify "Any class" with it.
I can't seem to find any direct parallel to Javas Class object that lets you specify a Class.

Note that I don't need to solve this specific problem, it is merely for illustration :)

Comment: Would this [work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygeQEYCsHFgXhgHgBUYEAPKBMAEwhgG8YwEB3GACgEoAuGAQzACeMAL4A+NlV5RePaACcAlmDgAaGMAA2vCBDToehDjByj6wgNwAoS5u20Awlp0BGepZgwADgFdUGhcAwIAC2CHC8AISyUIrKVsLWiCgYWFBsAOQhYbzpao52zhxWQA)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Java expert but in TypeScript you can force a generic type to be a class by using a Generic that needs to extend something like `{new (...args: any[]): any}`. Essentially this means that the type passed as an argument to the generic method has a corresponding constructor.

Make sure to use the **`typeof`** keyword when passing a class as a generic argument as it provides information about the type of the constructor definition.

```
class Test {}

function getObject<T extends {new (...args: any[]): any}>(data: string, type: T): T {
  return {} as T;
}

getObject<typeof Test>("", Test);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5WgbwL4FgBQAXAngBwFNoAVfIgXmXQwEsA7LAgJwDMxgiBJB5tjqzJhYBXOsCw0A9nWgBzAlgDyAIwBWBcQB5i0AgA9GdACYwkdAgHdoACgB09sE1kQAXNDB0cAbQC6ASjcPHBQAPmsjMCwwNwgsJnpZABpoXEI3YgCSZExoaCYFYSYZVHcYYgBuTGpMVKIADWhKWskWOAQISoxMeSU1DSxNZtb4SAgwgCJx5JGoP06elXUtUkIJqao5zAB6Ldy9vYA-I4PoAFoQkjJoAHIVgmvoPCZJADcaIwIYOkloAFtI4AAC2gLEkTBSgKIEBosjokUKRGu5is1kyQWutm6CkW-U03EYrHYBDWyVQmwwO32+2ONKOZwudxu+N4RIeT1e70+0G+fwBwNB4KwkOg0Nh8PyN2RNjRngxWN6SwGsXidFkJI2nUpVNytJO50uhBuyoSDyMki53ywIsiNAgLBwEKIwGkyrA9CtSMs0saF3RtiAA)